# how to output program into HTML file in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I am trying to output a my data in my COBOL file into a HTML file. What are the steps to create and write data into a file so it outputs as a valid HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

Enables you to embed HTML into a COBOL CGI program for output to a Web browser via the EHTML preprocessor.

General Format

```
EXEC HTML
  [htmloutput]
  [copy "file.htm"]
END-EXEC
```

Parameters
htmloutput
(HTML statements (markup) for output to a Web browser.)

file.htm
(A file containing HTML markup.)

Comment: Do I just write html code after EXEC HTML?